# python3: Why does python reorder my prints and seems to forget function parameters that later appear again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, keyword-argument, default-arguments

I wanted to have a small function that prints an error message and then terminates the program.
When I changed the program termination method from `sys.exit()` to `raise RuntimeError()`, suddenly my message stopped being printed. I then debugged the method for some time, but I do not understand why the order of the prints is inverted and why python thinks my `*args` are empty.

My Code is:

```py
def original_fail(retcode=1, *args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, **kwargs) # the actual site of the print
    raise RuntimeError() # no printing, only raises method

def debug_fail(retcode=1, *args, **kwargs):
    print("called")
    print("args=", args, "kwargs=", kwargs)
    print(*args, **kwargs) # the actual site of the print
    print("printed")
    #raise RuntimeError()
    print("before termination")
    exit(retcode)
    print("after termination")

debug_fail("outside message")
```

and it prints

```sh
$ python3 /tmp/soverflow.py
called
args= () kwargs= {}

printed
before termination
outside message
```

What I find especially irritating is that python thinks `args` and `kwargs` to be empty, and thus also printing an empty line, but still at the very end prints `outside message`.
When I don't put `retcode=1` in the function, it works, but I want to have that parameter.
EDIT: Apparently the behavior comes from `retcode` becoming `"outside message"`, but thats not what I want. I want all arguments to be passed to print except a keyword argument `retcode` that I want to filter out. How do I do that?

Im using python 3.8.6 on a Fedora 32 machine:

```sh
sh-5.0$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.6
sh-5.0$ uname -a
Linux workstation-fedora 5.9.10-100.fc32.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 23 18:12:36 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to understand that behavior and what to do to actually use `raise RuntimeError()` in my implementation

Comment: Your argument is going to become `retcode` since it is the first one.

Comment: Ahhh apparenty `exit()` can take a string and print that (I expected it to throw). What do I do to print all arguments and filter out an argument `retcode` and only pass that on?